# Convert special chars to RAW format in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, character-encoding, oracle10g

How do I convert a special chars like '#' to RAW format in Oracle?I need it for searching in the blob like this.

following code is giving me all rows in table as a result

```
dbms_lob.instr(gob_a_document, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('C#')) <> 0)
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: `#` isn't a special character in most datasets - was this originally a different character?

Comment: No, I am sorry, I considered it as a special character because statement which contains it is giving me a strange result(as I've described above).

Comment: May be a stupid question, but have you determined that at least some of the rows in the table point to files that *do not* contain `C#` in them?

Comment: Yes, it's a file that contains a records of job candidates CV's, so most of them don't even know what C# is:-)(so it's not in their CV)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code out, and I think it's correct for that line.  On Oracle 11.2.0.1, I used your code to do something basically the same:

```
select v.* 
from   V_INCOMING_MAIL v 
where  dbms_lob.instr(v.message_text, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('C#'),1,1) <> 0;
```

This selected 9 rows out of the 15 thousand in the view.  From an ad-hoc sampling of those rows and some others, that seems to be working OK.

So, perhaps the problem lies in the other lines in the SQL statement?